# What will (getDirectoryFiles "" (dir </> "//*.c")) actually match?

Tags: shake-build-system

I was experiencing unnecessary rebuilds while using this matching pattern:

```
getDirectoryFiles "" $ "foo" </> "//*.c"
```

I'm on Linux so from my understanding the second argument will evaluate to

```
"foo///*.c"
```

and I presume that it would be incorrect to replace this with

```
"foo" </> "/*.c"
```

as that would not work on windows? On Linux however this works as I expect it to.

From testing I concluded that the pattern matched files outside of "foo" which makes no sense in my world. As an example the pattern above would match both testA.c and testB.c in a directory structure like the one below.

```
foo/testA.c
bar/testB.c
```

I see now that there is a `<//>` operator, so maybe I should be using `"foo" <//> "*.c"` instead but still. This was quite nasty to find and what does `"foo///*.c"` actually do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `</>` operator is defined so that:

`"foo" </> "//*.c" == "//*.c"`

That means that using `</>` to create a `//` value is almost never the right thing to do. `<//>` solves that, but as you note, it's not predictable and quite nasty.

The solution is using `foo/**/*.c` as an alternative pattern to `foo//*.c`. The advantage of the first form is that it is perfectly predictable and works well with `</>`, eliminating the need for `<//>`. Since Shake 0.15.6 that has been a permissible alternative, and in Shake 0.16 it will probably be recommended over `//`.

As to your other questions: 1) for Windows you can use either `/` or `\` interchangeably in pattern values, so writing `foo//*.c` literally is just fine. 2) `foo///*.c` is equivalent to `foo//*.c`, and there are extensive test suites for such forms in Shake.

Comment: Thanks, good explanation! Unfortunate combination of `</>` and `"//"`. It makes me happy that it will be replaced in 0.16. In 0.15.11 the documentation says "Currently considered experimental" which resulted in me not even testing it.